# DOM - storing and outputting values?

Tags: javascript, html

if anyone could help with this and explain where I'm going wrong it would be very much appreciated. I'm trying to write a function that will run when the button element is clicked. Right now it's just running as soon as the first prompt stores the name variable.

**HTML:**

```
<body>

  <h1>Calculate a right angle:</h1>

  <form action="index.html" method="post">
    <label for="first">First side:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstSide">
    <br><br>
    <label for="second">Second side:</label>
    <input type="text" id="secondSide">
    <br><br>
    <label for="long">Long side:</label>
    <input type="text" id="longSide">
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" id="calcBtn">Calculate Triangle</button>
  </form>

</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var firstname = prompt("Please enter your name");

//variables for storing value of each side of triangle
var ss1 = document.getElementById("firstSide").value;
var ss2 = document.getElementById("secondSide").value;
var ls1 = document.getElementById("longSide").value;


document.getElementById("calcBtn").addEventListener("click", calcTriangle(ss1, ss2, ls1));


//creating function for calculating the triangle
function calcTriangle(p1, p2, p3) {
  //formula for calculating if triangle is a right angle
  var answer = p1 * p1 + p2 * p2;
  if (answer == p3 * p3) {
    alert("Hi " + firstname + ", this is a right angle.");
  } else {
    alert("Hi " + firstname + ", this is not a right angle.");
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone able to help with this.

Comment: Why don't you just ask for the name when the function _calcTriangle_ is called?

Comment: Before I provide an answer, I would like to see the javascript in "js/mathRevision.js".  Besides that, you are not calling the function you wrote when the button element is clicked (unless this is part of your external JS library's logic) AND the values p1, p2, p3 need to be updated from the LATEST values in the input elements prior to calling your function.

Comment: Guess I overlooked your addEventListener code :/, BUT you need to pass the LATEST values of your input elements to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your addEventListener expects a reference of the function,try this

```
.addEventListener("click", calcTriangle)
```

when you write it with parenthesis will invoke the function

and  you can pass the parameters you declared like this

```
function calcTriangle(ss1, ss2, ls1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This example denotes the click event handling in the button element and passes the current input element values to your function.  I also added some basic validation logic to determine if numeric values are specified.  Let me know how it goes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sample</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   var firstname = prompt("Please enter your name");
   if(firstname.trim().length == 0) firstname = "(Unknown)";

//creating function for calculating the triangle
function calcTriangle(p1, p2, p3) {
  try
  {

    if(isNaN(p1) || isNaN(p2) || isNaN(p3) || p1.trim().length==0 || p2.trim().length==0 || p3.trim().length==0)
    {
      alert("One or more values are not valid numbers!");
      return;
    }

    //formula for calculating if triangle is a right angle

    var answer = p1 * p1 + p2 * p2;

    if (answer == p3 * p3) {
      alert("Hi " + firstname + ", this is a right angle.");
    } else {
      alert("Hi " + firstname + ", this is not a right angle.");
    }

  }
  catch(e)
  {
    alert("calcTriangle Error:  " + e.Message)
  }
}    

  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Calculate a right angle:</h1>

  <form action="index.html" method="post">
    <label for="first">First side:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstSide">
    <br><br>
    <label for="second">Second side:</label>
    <input type="text" id="secondSide">
    <br><br>
    <label for="long">Long side:</label>
    <input type="text" id="longSide">
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" id="calcBtn" onclick="calcTriangle(document.getElementById('firstSide').value, document.getElementById('secondSide').value, document.getElementById('longSide').value)">Calculate Triangle</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```